# Kubernetes Ingress - Refuse connection if no match or IP (i.e. disable defaultBackend and don't respond at all) How?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

For PCI we need to make sure that absolutely no response comes out that isn't in TLS with a valid certificate. That means that even responding with a certificate that doesn't match the domain is not allowed.  That means that responding at all to the IP address directly isn't allowed.

So I'm trying to configure K8s so that it simply won't respond at all to a request unless there is a rules match. (i.e. completely disable default backend with no response.)

I'm using nginx.ingress.

Is there a way to make it just not respond if no rules match?

Comment: You *have* to accept the connection, because your HTTP client needs to at least complete the initial connection setup and send the HTTP request before the ingress service is able to determine whether or not there exists a matching ingress rule.

Comment: Nginx itself allows a no response or an outright reject based on the requested host even in SSL via the SNI. What I'm looking for is a way to do what NGINX itself supports, and just hard reject or not respond at all if it isn't a host that is recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Like `larks` said it’s impossible to restrict an HTTP client from completing the initial handshake using normal k8s implementation. However the same can be achieved by using a WAF (Web Application Firewall) or similar solutions that act as shields and has multiple configurations so the initial validation happens even before it reaches your environment and you can enforce strict rules as required using WAF.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. I can easily make nginx itself just refuse to respond at all if the URL isn't one I want to see. SNI ensures that it's transmitted before the SSL handshake, and even if it wasn't it's allowing unencrypted through to the default backend and responding which is a violation of PCI rules. It cannot respond or it MUST be an encryption upgrade and the CERT must then match whatever the host that was requested (in this case the IP)

Comment: @JamesHancock I think I'm a little confused. Can you confirm where you are validating this? is it before reaching your application or is it before reaching your network..?

Comment: @JamesHancock I don't know who has downvoted this, it requires further discussion might be on serverfault forum however it still involves a bit of coding.

Comment: All PCI scans do this. I'm infering what they're doing but I can see it here. If you don't put in a default backend it replies anyhow. If you do, it doesn't force it to SSL even though I have force SSL set and it works when you hit a rule.  But really on IP I don't want any response at all. If anything, just "bug off".